# Is there 3 processes when start the sshd service in cygwin?

Tags: cygwin, sshd

After I have started sshd service in my cygiwn(1.7.33 64bit on win8.1 64bit), there has 3 processes( in red box) and two of them have dynamic pids(yellow box). If I use kill command for the process in the yellow box, it responce no such process, but if you use the ps command again, you will see they are still there, but with a different pids.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAU4e.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6all.png